# How to change the APK icon?

Tags: android, eclipse, icons, apk

I use Eclipse to code Android apps.

And when I put a apk file in the cell, the APK icon is always show as a box icon.

How to change the APK icon?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In The left side of Eclipse u can see Project Explorer ! open your project at almost end of it there is a file called    AndroidManifest.xml, just open it and choose Application Tab and then choose your icon , dont forget to put your App Icon ( *.png) in Res >> drawable-hdpi

Comment: doesn't help people who aren't using eclipse

Answer (score 6):

Goto Manifest File,in application tag give icon of application whatever you want as below

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

here ic_launcher is my application icon,you can give any icon as per your requirnment.

Answer (score 2):

Check android manifest file, check for android:icon tag, and change it to new image.

Answer (score 2):

in your manifest file change the launcher icon of main activity(launcher activity) change icon

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

by default it takes ic_launcher change it to your icon

Answer (score 0):

You can change the icon of APK in your `AndroidMenifest.xml` file under `Application` Tag.Like mention below.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/Your_App_Logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your android manifest file 
android:icon="@drawable/yourdrawable". Make sure you have the image in your drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open AndroidManifest.xml
2. Change application `android:icon="@drawable/your_logeHere"`